# Apache redirect ambiguous uri

Tags: apache, redirect, .htaccess

I am using Apache .htaccess to do redirection:

```
RedirectMatch "^/mysubpage/?" http://domain.com/page [R=301,L]
```

Link: http://domain.com/mysubpage

But when the page loads, the link changes to: http://domain.com/page/**?uri=/mysubpage/**

Why does it append the "?uri" query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your http://domain.com/subpage is already a rewritten URL?!

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch "^/mysubpage/(.*)" http://domain.com/page/$1? [R=301,L]
```

The Questionmark at the end of your redirect-destination is to prevent appending the old querystring to it (which is default behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the ? in your redirect match regex, but I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  If you are wanting to capture the glob following the last slash (what is appearing in your uri= substring) and use that as part of a different URI then what you want is something like this

```
RedirectMatch "^/mysubpage/(.*)" http://domain.com/page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will take any request to `http://domain.com/mysubpage/alpha.php` and redirect it permanently to `http://domain.com/page/alpha.php`.  If on the other hand you don't care about what is after the slash in the request to mysubpage then you can do something like this:

```
RedirectMatch "^/mysubpage/.*" http://domain.com/page [R=301,L]
```

That will drop the rest of the request and redirect to `http://domain.com/page`.

HTH

Comment: I don't care about what is after the slash. I tried your 2nd example but still puts the old uri as a query string after redirecting: `http://domain.com/page/?uri=/mysubpage/`

Comment: Also the '?' in my RedirectMatch is to mark the preceding / as optional.